# Altering default Slider Behavior in Windows Phone 7 Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'd like to know if there is a way to update the thumb indicator of the slider template directly to the place where the user clicks, the default behavior is that you have to hold the tap till the the thumb reaches the target.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any properties that allow you to switch on this kind of behavior.

So the way to do this is by sub classing the Slider and overriding the [OnMouseLeftButtonDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.onmouseleftbuttondown%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)